# IIS 7 run asp.net mvc 3 app beside webforms app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I have an existing webforms application running at:

```
demo.bla.com/dotnettwoapp
```

with the binding demo.bla.com in iis 7.

I would like to get a asp.net mvc 3 application running under:

```
demo.bla.com/mvcapp
```

My first attempt was to create a new site:

Mvcapp

but IIS 7 complaints about the duplicate binding. I did a few google searches but could not find anything. Could anyone please point me in the right direction on what to do in my situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add it as an application under an existing site, you don't want to add a new site.  In IIS, right-click on the existing site and choose "Add Application".

Comment: actually, that's what I just managed to do before looking at your answer. Thanks!